# Is it feasible to expose undergraduates to a "map"-centric point of view early on?

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, course-design

**Question:** Would it be feasible to teach undergraduate math students a "map"-centric view early on? If so, how early on?

Now that I'm preparing for a phd program, I'm also reflecting on my undergraduate education and wishing that I had adopted a so-called "map"-centric point of view earlier on. Here are toy-examples:

> A point $x \in X$ is a map $f:\{\bullet\} \hookrightarrow X$

Or maybe the product as the cartesian product $A \times B$ equipped with canonical projections vs. $A \sqcup B$ (and injections.)

Either way, these are things of a categorical "flavor" that probably wouldn't have really profoundly affected the math at an early stage, but *did* clarified some things for me later on (paths in $X$ are continuous maps $[0,1] \to X$, resp. the difference between direct product/sum in algebra.)

My question I guess is not really **should this be done?** But rather **can this be done successfully?**

An answer to my question would be either someone who has personally taken up this point of view (un)successfully or arguments for why it can(not) be done.

Comment: Sorry of "map-centric" point of view is not clear here. If asked to provide something more concrete, I would be glad to. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6543.pdf) is the article by Tom Leinster that offers some arguments for "rethinking set theory."

Comment: It's not clear to me what map centric means (is it commonly understood).  Also, what course does it apply to?  Are you assuming math major undergrads or science/engineering.  And (assuming math majors), what level of skill/smarts (best of the best?  average?  bottom tenth)?

Comment: One thought is I would be somewhat hesitant of assuming that you can introduce all kinds of abstractions earlier because they make sense to you NOW but would have been tough from the start.  I see this mental blinders a lot on here.

Comment: Finally it is not clear to me what the advantages of being more map centric are.

Comment: The category theorists agenda.

Comment: @guest I'm not sure that the term is commonly understood. Is there some part of it that is unclear? I guess I mean definitions and elements that make use of maps, so you don't have to keep making intricate and difficult arguments at the level of elements of sets. You might be right in your second comment. Again, I'm not really asking about whether or not its the right thing to do (I've already convinced myself of that) but rather if it is something that is doable, say, in a first algebra course. The main advantage imo is that this language  (and pov) dominates a lot of subjects.

Comment: @BPP I'm not sure that it is a category theorist's agenda. For example, I do not study category theory (I don't even get a real kick out of it, unless it relates to something I'm doing.) Perhaps category theorists are a nonempty proper subset of all advocates. Of course by that, I mean a nonconstant function $\{\mathrm{advocates}\} \to \mathbf 2$ haha ;)

Comment: I'm an undergraduate and this makes no sense to me :(

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee yeah, but it wasn’t taught in class, so that’s reasonable... maybe I was just wrong about all of this and it’s just something that I like.

Comment: What does the $\bullet $ in the point definition mean?

Comment: Reminds me of what the author tries to do [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/a-less-biased-definition-of-a-group/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

See the text "Conceptual Mathematics", which aims to teach set theory notions, among other things, from a categorical perspective to complete novices.

It's an excellent text!

https://www.amazon.ca/Conceptual-Mathematics-First-Introduction-Categories/dp/052171916X